# How to name HP/MP/Exp bars in a single word?

Tags: terminology, user-interface

I have one question related to game design.

In my prototype game, I have an options when you can change look of your HPbar, MPbar and Expbar. Actually I don't know how to easily name this option.

Currently have "player HP/MP/Exp bars - Value", but it doesn't look so great.

I am looking for a simple name for this, so I want to provide more understandable naming for player.

Answer (score 3):

In game design terms, HP, MP, and XP are all "resources" so we could call them "Resource Bars" collectively.

If that's too abstract/designer-y, we could also try "Points Bars" since it encompasses hit *Points*, magic *Points*, and experience *Points*

Of the three, "Health Bar" is probably the most familiar to players, so "Health & Other Bars" would give players a concrete example of what the setting affects.

Answer (score 1):

I very much disagree you'd refer to these as "resource bars" or "points bars" the first is ambiguous and the second I'm not sure is proper English.  The term I've *literally* heard and used to describe these concepts is ***Status Bars***.   they display your ***status***.  Wikipedia agrees with me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_bar and if you look up "status bar game" you will find it is used in *exactly* the way you describe ie in [aion online](http://gameguide.na.aiononline.com/aion/Status+Bar)

Answer (score 0):

It's often called the HUD or Heads Up Display. Though that encapsulates everything "cluttering" the edges of the screen in normal gameplay.

However a HUD design is very much tied to the identity of your game. Allowing too much customization can dilute how recognizable screenshots will be. In many cases it's better to settle on the single design.